# Vuex Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function despite getter being a function

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3

Encountering a problem with Vuex 4.0.2 where it throws an uncaught error indicating that a specific getter should be a function, even though it is indeed a function.

Error: `Uncaught Error: [vuex] getters should be function but "getters.teamsWithPlayers" is [].`

Vue 3.2.31

`store/index.js`

```
const getters = {
  teamsWithPlayers (state) {
    if (state.game.teams === undefined) {
      return state.game.teams
    }

    const teamsWithPlayersList = []

    state.game.teams.forEach(function (team) {
      const individualScores = []

      team.players = state.game.players.filter(player => team.name === player.team)
      team.players.forEach(function (player) {
        individualScores.push(player.score)
      })
      team.score = individualScores.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
      }, 0)

      teamsWithPlayersList.push(team)
    })

    return teamsWithPlayersList
  }
}

export default createStore({
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
})
~
```

Comment: can you show how have you imported getters?

Comment: They are not imported - they are defined in the same file as above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue was with the creation of the Vue app in `main.js`. As I was upgrading an existing project from Vue 2 to Vue 3, there was a reference to the old Vuex object instantiation that I did not catch.

The incorrect `main.js.`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import App from './App.vue' 
import router from './router' 
import store from '@/store' 
    
import '@/assets/styles/reveal_theme.scss' 
    
const vuexStore = new Vuex.Store(store)

const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(vuexStore)
app.mount('#app')
```

This is fixed by removing the references to the old `Vuex.Store`.

Corrected `main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue' 
import router from './router' 
import store from '@/store' 
    
const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(store)
app.mount('#app')
```